# Not-so-unexpected errors handling via custom Exceptions and a single Try ... Catch at Button callback level

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I am developing an Office AddIn (Excel + Word + PowerPoint).
The AddIn can be seen as a collection of small macros which perform relatively basic tasks. Each task is mostly independent from another, and called through the `RibbonUI`.

Since each macro is independant, I decided to implement a very basic `Error` trapping, directly through the `Ribbon callbacks`:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Try
        Call DoSomething
    Catch
        MsgBox("Something went wrong!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have a set of Custom `Exceptions` (for example if the `selection` `range` is incompatible with the macro). In my code, I `Throw` costom `Exceptions` when I know the error was from the User. So in my `Catch` I check the `Type` of `Exception`:

- If it is a custom `Exception`, then I `LogEvent` as a `Warning`, and indicate to the User they did not follow the right procedure.
- If it is a native `Exception`, then I `LogEvent` as an `Error`, and I invite the User to click a [Report Bug] button. This button exports the Log and sends it to me.

**My question**: I have seen comments indicating Custom Exceptions should be reserved for Class Libraries whose purpose is to be distributed and re-used by others. For example see [Cody Gray post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086116/vb-net-examples-of-user-defined-exceptions) who suggests to always use native Exceptions.
Could anyone explain to me what problems I should expect my code to encounter once distributed ?

---

### RibbonUI.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class RibbonExcel

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_GetWeightedAverage_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button_GetWeightedAverage.Click
        Try

            Call GetWeightedAverage()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Select Case ex.GetType
                Case GetType(CustomExceptions.WrongSelectionException)
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Debug",
                                "UI Warning: {ExMessage}".Replace("{ExMessage}", ex.Message) & vbNewLine _
                                & "In: {ExSource}".Replace("{ExSource}", ex.Source) & vbNewLine _
                                & "Trace: {ExStack}".Replace("{ExStack}", ex.StackTrace),
                                EventLogEntryType.Warning)
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong: {ExMessage}".Replace("{ExMessage}", ex.Message) & vbNewLine _
                                                         & "Read the Help File for further assistance. If the problem remains, please click the [Report Bug] button.",
                                                         "MyApp",
                                                         Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                         Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                                                         Nothing,
                                                         Nothing,
                                                         "MyHelpFGile.hlp", "GetWeightedAverage")
                Case Else
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Debug",
                                "UI Error: {ExMessage}" & vbNewLine _
                                & "In: {ExSource}" & vbNewLine _
                                & "Trace: {ExStack}".Replace("{ExMessage}", ex.Message).Replace("{ExSource}", ex.Source).Replace("{ExStack}", ex.StackTrace),
                                EventLogEntryType.Error)
                    MsgBox("Something went completely wrong! If the problem remains, please click the [Report Bug] button.", vbCritical Or vbOKOnly)
            End Select
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

---

### Module1.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1

    Sub GetWeightedAverage()

        If Not Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType Is GetType(Excel.Range) Then Throw New CustomExceptions.WrongSelectionException("You must select cells.")
        Dim Selection As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection
        If Selection.Columns.Count <> 2 Then Throw New CustomExceptions.WrongSelectionException("You must select 2 columns.")

        Dim TotalValues As Double = 0
        Dim TotalWeight As Double = 0
        For Each Row As Excel.Range In Selection.Rows
            TotalValues += Row.Cells(1, 1).value2 * Row.Cells(0, 1).value2
            TotalWeight += Row.Cells(1, 2).value2
        Next

        MsgBox("Weighted average is {result}.".Replace("{result}", TotalValues / TotalWeight))

    End Sub

End Module

Namespace Global.CustomExceptions
    <Serializable()>
    Public Class WrongSelectionException : Inherits System.Exception

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal message As String)
            MyBase.New(message)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal message As String, ByVal innerException As System.Exception)
            MyBase.New(message, innerException)
        End Sub

        <System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical()>
        Protected Sub New(ByVal info As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, ByVal context As System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
            MyBase.New(info, context)
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: The way I see the answer is: Exceptions are things unexpected that happen. In a public library, you'll expect user to send specific parameter, if those parameter are wrong then it's an exception. Now, if you use your own library then you should always send the proper parameter since you built it yourself. So, going by this logic, you would just need to build a method "IsSelectionProper" and call this method instead of throwing an exception. *Note* I don't want to say if any of this is right or wrong. Just what I think was meant in the answer.

Comment: Sorry it looks like the notification for your comment got lost. Thanks for the feedback!